# Highchart how to animate from the xaxis bottom line upward

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am getting a issue with highcharts animation from the middle instead of from the xAxis upwards can someone suggest a way to do this.

I am updating the chart as follows.

```
chart.series[0].setData(e.data1);
chart.series[1].setData(e.data2);
chart.series[2].setData(e.data3);
```

Here is the result I am getting, is there a way I can anchor the columns to the bottom xAxis to animate up.

[image]

Thanks

JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/wofcnsxr/

Comment: Could you post live example of your issue? Or post the code you are using in your chart?

Comment: sure ill set one up in js fiddle i am using highcharts with Appcelerator so i will need to grab some dummy data

Comment: question updated ;) http://jsfiddle.net/wofcnsxr/

Comment: Do you need to use setData? Maybe you can use point.update() in your case? It has different animation. You can also change this animation yourself. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/e0qxfLtt/25/

Comment: hi @GrzegorzBlachliński unfortunately yes setData is needed for my setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get rid of the blanks left by the bar growing again by updating the series instead of hiding them.
So i declared an empty series data : `var empty = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];`

And then, instead of hiding the series you wanted to hide, I filled them with 0 data :

```
    chart.series[1].hide();
    chart.series[2].hide();
```

becomes

```
    chart.series[1].setData(empty);
    chart.series[2].setData(empty);
```

and there is no need for the `show()` anymore

Here is the working js fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/wofcnsxr/2/

Hope it solves your problem